# perform event just before page change

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker

I have a React app. In that react app, I have certain button click events which are triggered just before page changes (analytics event)

```
  sendEvent('xyz')
  let win = window.open(`${PAGE_PATHS.dashboard}`, "_self");
                if (win !== null) {
                    win.focus();
                }
```

Where event is

```
async event(name, data) {
    await this.sendEvent(name, data)
}
```

Where sendEvent() is

```
async sendEvent(name, data) {
// some code
axios.post(url, payload, userConfig)
return 
}
```

Now, because of the current structure, the events sometimes don't get logged. There are two things which I could do here.

1. Use `await` but I don't want to do it because sending event and getting response might take some time (user experience) and I don't care about the response
2. Use setTimeout.

For some reason I don't like either one of the approach. Is there a way, I can have the task to execute (if it isn't completed) even after the webpage have changed it's href? maybe using service or webworker

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is commonly called "sending a beacon", and there is a method in the Web standards especially for this case: [`Navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon).

This method will allow your script to send a request to the web server, even after the page has been killed.

I am not an axios ninja, so I can't tell you how it should be rewritten to perform the same, but certainly it can.
The basic usage is:

```
navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
```

where `data` can be an `ArrayBuffer`, a `TypedArray`, a `Blob`, a `DOMString`, `FormData` or an `URLSearchParams` object.